# How to increase font vertical spacing by using fonts.conf file?

Tags: centos, fonts, fontconfig

I'm noticed in NetBeans in Windows 10 - if I set editor font to "Courier New" - line spacing is normal. Then if font is set to "DialogInput" - line spacing is about 1:2, easier to read/work. "DialogInput" font is simply "Courier New", but in this case somehow modified? On CentOS I see no difference. Is it possible to match "DialogInput" font with "Courier New" plus some line spacing properties? I can set line spacing in NetBeans properties at `~/.netbeans/11.1/config/Editors/Preferences/org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-CustomPreferences.xml` with:

```
<entry javaType="java.lang.Float" name="line-height-correction" xml:space="preserve">
```

But trying to find if it is possible to do that with `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf` file.

**EDIT:**

`Dialog` and `DialogInput` fonts are controlled by Java. I found that in JDK12 file (both on CentOS and Win10) `/usr/java/latest/lib/psfontj2d.properties` contains:

```
#
# Legacy logical font family names and logical font aliases should all
# map to the primary logical font names.
#
serif=serif
times=serif
timesroman=serif
sansserif=sansserif
helvetica=sansserif
dialog=sansserif
dialoginput=monospaced
monospaced=monospaced
courier=monospaced
```

So those fonts are simply `sansserif` and `monospaced`. And NetBeans settings file `~/.netbeans/11.1/config/Editors/Preferences/org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-CustomPreferences.xml` is exatcly the same on CentOS and Win10. So still can not uderstand this different behaviour..

Comment: Not possible AFAIK.

Comment: Some info about font properties here: [FONT PROPERTIES](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/fonts-conf.5.html). If NetBeans on Win10 accepts one of them, on CentOS it should do the same (binaries identical). Just need to find out which one - perhaps `line-height-correction`, I will try tp lace it in `fonts.conf`.

Comment: It's likely that Windows applies some tweaks to set a fixed line spacing for the DialogInput font. If you're not content with your workaround for Netbeans I'll suggest to you to modify the font's line spacing in FontForge.